# Axes in a vector plot

Tags: differential-equations

Consider:

```
sys = {u (1 - u + a v), r v (1 - v + b u)};
vp = VectorPlot[
  sys /. {a -> 2, b -> 3, r -> 1}, {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2},
  VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None},
  VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]},
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

The axes are not drawn. Now, I know I can fix this by doing the following.

```
sys = {u (1 - u + a v), r v (1 - v + b u)};
vp = VectorPlot[
  sys /. {a -> 2, b -> 3, r -> 1}, {u, -0.1, 2}, {v, -0.1, 2},
  VectorScale -> {0.045, 0.9, None},
  VectorStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8]},
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

But I am wondering if I am missing something here?

Comment: In Version 9 both graphics look the same

Comment: They *shouldn't* look the same and in v8 don't. He is, after all, specifying different ranges for `u` and `v`. I cannot get Mathematica to show a frame *and* axes if the origin is too close to the frame. In fact, his solution does not "fix" this in v8. I need to specify ranges for `u` and `v` as `{-0.2,2}` for the axes to show up.